# Determine which function to call based on two values

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I'm building a physics engine as a learning experience and I'm a bit stuck when it comes to a solid implementation of the different collision and resolving functions. The math for it is no problem, but rather how to check for it.

I've got seperate objects for box, ellipse, line etc which all extend from a parent 'physics entity' object, but have some own properties like their shape. Somewhat like this:

```
function PhysicsEntity(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.velocity = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
}

function Box(x, y, width, height) {
    PhysicsEntity.apply(this, [x, y]);

    this.width = width || 150;
    this.height = height || 50;
    this.shape = 'box';
}
```

Now, when two objects are close to each other I want to check if they're actually colliding, but to do that I need to calculate some things a bit differently for each combination of shapes (box&box, box&ellipse, ellipse&line etc)

One of my approaches was to just put the two shapes in an array, sort it alphabetically, concat it and use that as a key for an object full of functions:

```
var collisions = {
    'box_ellipse': function() {
        // Collision check
    }
}

isColliding(Entity1, Entity2) {
    var shapes = [Entity1, Entity2];

    if(Entity1.shape.localCompare(Entity2.shape) > 0) {
        entities.reverse();
    }

    collisions[entities[0] + '_' + entities[1]]();
}
```

Although this works, it feels **really** hacked and fragile.

So, in short I'm basically looking for an elegant way to call a function or something simmilar based on two randomly sorted, unknown values that doesn't involve dozen lines of spaghetti if/switch code.

Comment: Maybe `fn = [Entity1.shape,entity2.shape].sort().join('_')`, then `collisions[fn](...)` though you might want to check that *collisions[fn]* exists first.

Comment: Looks a bit cleaner and is way easier to understand what is going on, but I don't like the idea itself of using a concated string as an objects' key to call a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var collisions = {
    'box_ellipse': function(box, ellipse) {
        // Collision check
    }
    // other combos here
}

isColliding(Entity1, Entity2) {
    var s1 = Entity1.shape;
    var s2 = Entity2.shape;

    if(collisions[s1 + '_' + s2] !== undefined) // the collision function exists
        collisions[s1 + '_' + s2](Entity1, Entity2); // call it on the entities in order
    else // they must be reversed
        collisions[s2 + '_' + s1](Entity2, Entity1);

}
```

**Note:** All combos (ignoring the order) should be defined in the `collisions` object. If the possible shapes are: `"box"`, `"circle"`, `"triangle"`, then the `collisions` object should contain 6 keys which are:

1. `box_triangle` or `triangle_box`
2. `box_circle` or `circle_box`
3. `circle_triangle` or `triangle_circle`
4. `box_box`
5. `circle_cirlce`
6. `triangle_triangle`

A function for the key `shapeA_shapeB` will accept two entities as parameters: one of `shapeA` and another of `shapeB` in that order then check for the collision of the two entities.